# PhoneTextBox cursor resets after applying text suggestion

Tags: windows-phone-8, textbox, windows-phone, wptoolkit

I'm using the PhoneTextBox from the Windows Phone Toolkit with *InputScope="Text"* to get autocorrect and text suggestions. While typing in the keyboard the text suggestions appears above the keyboard and I choose one of them. Immediately after the suggestion is taken the cursor of the TextBox resets to the start position. So if I continue typing then the new text is inserted at the beginning of the TextBox.

Here's an example: After choosing the text suggestion "Tests" the cursor begin of line.

[image: PhoneTextBox]

EDIT: 
The issue is caused by an calling of *BindingExpression.UpdateSource()* within the TextChanged event handler. I can't find a workaround so I created an issue: https://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/11766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a Windows 8 phone with the regular Phone 8.0 SDK.

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox InputScope="Text" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"/>
```

It works fine on my end.  I would check if there are any attached events (maybe TextChanged) that would cause the cursor to reset.

Comment: This could be possible becuase I use an AttachedProperty for updating the text binding. I will check it later!

Comment: You are right. The problem was the attached property but I don't know why I get this problem with the PhoneTextBox and not with the default TextBox. Do you have another idea for updating the Text binding?